# Laravel: /resource gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to create the url `my-domain.dev/resources` so I added this to my Route file:

```
Route::get('/resources', function(){
  dd('hi');
});
```

However, this is not working. I only get a 403 Forbidden error:

[image]

All other routes are working fine. Is it not possible to set this route in Laravel 5.5 ?

Comment: what is your server root of nginx conf?

Comment: The code is good but problem is in your server root dir

Answer (score 0):

`/resources` is already reserved by the folder name in laravel folder. When you try to access this url it will point to the directory '/resources' in your project folder and will throw 403.

You can replace `/resources` with `/resource` and it will work.